# xhtml2pdf background-image is not scaling

Tags: html, css, django, pdf, xhtml2pdf

I'm generating an pdf with `xhtml2pdf` library, and I have a strange situation regarding background image.

Image is displayed but it does not fit the `@page`, it's setup something like this

```
    @page {
        size: {% block page_size %}A4 {% endblock %};
                        background: url("{% static 'folder/background.png' %}") no-repeat center center fixed;
                        @frame content_farme {
                            margin-top: 70pt;
                            margin-bottom: 60pt;
                            margin-left: 30pt;
                            margin-right: 30pt;
                            @bottom-right {
                                font-size: 10px;
              margin: 40pt -10pt 0 0;
                    {% block page_foot_extra_styles %}{% endblock %}
                    content: {% block page_foot %}"Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages){% endblock %};
            }
            @top-left {
                font-size: 10px;
                font-weight: bold;
            {% block page_header_extra_styles %}{% endblock %}
                content: {% block page_head %}{% endblock %};
            }
                        }
        }
```

I want it to be placed in my `@page`, I've tried everything, as I understand standard `css` property are not working like it should, so how can I scale this `background` in `xhtml2pdf` there is a nice [test](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/test/test-background-img.html) file in docs but I didn't find it useful, did someone have this kind off issues, and how did you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this problem I've concluded that this only reproduces on Firefox (my version is 50.1.0), I have tried on multiple machines the same things is happening, it's like the background is offset from the A4 `@page`, Chrome, Microsoft Edge and the rest of the browsers are fine and they don't reproduce this kind a bug.